# SVG size in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, svg

I'm having trouble making SVG images work across browsers. At first I had a lot of trouble with IE 8, but after lots of workarounds that finally works. Now Safari is the big problem, surprisingly, since I thought that would have strong support for SVG from what I've read.

So here's the problem:

I'm producing HTML pages for webhelp applications, and this is done through XSL. This transform produces HTML files with object elements that include the svg files:

```
<object
  type="image/svg+xml" class="image"
  id="Push12Principschema__image_538dabf9-da61-46a1-99c4-863a880aed46"
  data="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Ettrors.svg"> </object>
```

Now, the SVG files have a viewbox with fixed values in pixels, and then width and height set at 100%, to make it possible to scale the image by scaling the wrapping object element.

So I use jQuery to set the width (height isn't needed for most browsers) at first to 50%. Then if the user clicks on the image it scales the object width to 100%.

This works fine in all browsers except Safari.

To begin with, Safari doesn't even show the svg image in full size (or even 50% if I set that), but a very scaled down size, probably the size of the viewbox values.

So even though I try (for testing) to set the width of the object tag to 100%, that doesn't matter. All other browsers take up all available space on the page if I do this.

And of course by the same token, scaling up doesn't work either (if I initially set it to 50%).

I also tried to specifically set the height to 100%. That doesn't help either.

The only thing that seems to work in Safari is to set it to a fixed pixel value for both width and height. That shows the image in a decent size.

But that is not something I can easily do, because I don't know the exact size of the images, or even the ratio.

So why does it work in all browsers, but not Safari, and what do I do for Safari support?

EDIT: Sorry, posted the wrong code for the object element used. I actually create several, and hide irrelevant ones for different browsers. The one I changed here now is the one shown to all browsers but IE8.

EDIT 2:

At the risk of making this a very lengthy post, I thought it might be a good idea to post the SVG code. What I have is a large number of SVG images, saved in Illustrator from EPS images. These get fixed pixel values in width and height, which doesn't work for scaling in most browsers, I have learned. So I have search-replaced the width and height attributes using XPath to 100% values. Also, because I noticed that there was something wrong with the artboard in most images, I tried resaving the svg images with the "Save for web and devices" command in Illustrator, selecting SVG again as output format. This fixed the artboard at least when you view it in there.

So, here's one where I have done both the "Save for web and devices" to try to fix the artboard, and also changed the width and height to 100%:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
]>
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-0.5 -0.21 613 485"
     overflow="visible" enable-background="new -0.5 -0.21 613 485" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
<path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M90.626,274.561
    c0-115.164,93.354-208.518,208.515-208.518c115.16,0,208.515,93.354,208.515,208.518c0,115.161-93.355,208.507-208.515,208.507
    C183.979,483.068,90.626,389.722,90.626,274.561L90.626,274.561z"/>
<path fill="#ECEDED" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M104.269,274.561
    c0-107.627,87.248-194.875,194.872-194.875c107.625,0,194.875,87.248,194.875,194.875c0,107.626-87.25,194.867-194.875,194.867
    C191.517,469.428,104.269,382.187,104.269,274.561L104.269,274.561z"/>
<path fill="#ECEDED" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M136.748,274.561
    c0-89.693,72.703-162.396,162.391-162.396c89.695,0,162.396,72.706,162.396,162.396c0,89.688-72.704,162.389-162.396,162.389
    C209.451,436.95,136.748,364.246,136.748,274.561L136.748,274.561z"/>
<path fill="#ECEDED" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M171.824,274.561
    c0-70.319,57-127.319,127.314-127.319c70.314,0,127.319,57.002,127.319,127.319c0,70.316-57.005,127.312-127.319,127.312
    C228.824,401.873,171.824,344.877,171.824,274.561L171.824,274.561z"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M274.895,64.161H17.568 M267.857,484.169
    H17.568 M45.729,86.842v374.646"/>
<polygon points="45.729,88.154 37.848,88.154 45.729,68.455 53.606,88.154 "/>
<polygon points="45.729,460.183 53.606,460.183 45.729,479.877 37.848,460.183 "/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M612,182.266H323.888 M612,366.844H335.624
     M593.232,207.293V348.08"/>
<polygon points="593.232,208.605 585.351,208.605 593.232,188.906 601.114,208.605 "/>
<polygon points="593.232,346.763 601.114,346.763 593.232,366.467 585.351,346.763 "/>
<text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 556.5376 309.7231)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="36.535">d</text>
<text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 565.4243 291.2427)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="36.535">u</text>
<text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 30.4517 278.7349)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="36.535">D</text>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M205.919,274.561
    c0-51.488,41.734-93.222,93.219-93.222c51.488,0,93.222,41.734,93.222,93.222c0,51.48-41.733,93.224-93.222,93.224
    C247.656,367.785,205.919,326.042,205.919,274.561L205.919,274.561z"/>
<path fill="#B1B3B4" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M227.433,274.561
    c0-39.606,32.104-71.71,71.708-71.71c39.601,0,71.713,32.104,71.713,71.71c0,39.604-32.112,71.705-71.713,71.705
    C259.538,346.264,227.433,314.162,227.433,274.561L227.433,274.561z"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M390.374,250.593V35.22 M368.476,250.593
    V35.22 M448.254,46.701h-36.514"/>
<polygon points="413.055,46.701 413.055,54.579 393.35,46.701 413.055,38.821 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" x1="327.018" y1="46.701" x2="342.413" y2="46.701"/>
<polygon points="341.095,46.701 341.095,38.821 360.802,46.701 341.095,54.579 "/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 415.5356 30.4517)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="36.535">s</text>
</svg>
```

And here's one (different image) with the width and height values changed to 100%, but without doing the "Save for web and devices" command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 121.057 96.619" enable-background="new 0 0 121.057 96.619"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M17.357,56.287c0-22.063,17.886-39.95,39.951-39.95
        s39.95,17.886,39.95,39.95c0,22.064-17.885,39.951-39.95,39.951S17.357,78.351,17.357,56.287L17.357,56.287z"/>
    <path fill="#ECEDED" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M19.971,56.287
        c0-20.62,16.716-37.336,37.337-37.336c20.62,0,37.336,16.716,37.336,37.336c0,20.621-16.717,37.338-37.336,37.338
        C36.687,93.625,19.971,76.908,19.971,56.287L19.971,56.287z"/>
    <path fill="#ECEDED" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M26.194,56.287
        c0-17.183,13.93-31.113,31.114-31.113c17.184,0,31.114,13.93,31.114,31.113c0,17.186-13.93,31.115-31.114,31.115
        C40.124,87.402,26.194,73.472,26.194,56.287L26.194,56.287z"/>
    <path fill="#ECEDED" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M32.417,56.287
        c0-13.747,11.144-24.891,24.892-24.891c13.747,0,24.891,11.144,24.891,24.891c0,13.748-11.145,24.893-24.891,24.893
        C43.561,81.179,32.417,70.035,32.417,56.287L32.417,56.287z"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M52.663,15.976H3.359 M51.313,96.449
        H3.359 M8.754,20.322v71.781"/>
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="8.754,20.573 7.245,20.573 8.754,16.799 10.264,20.573 8.754,20.573  "/>
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="8.754,91.851 10.264,91.851 8.754,95.626 7.245,91.851 8.754,91.851  "/>

        <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" x1="117.459" y1="41.51" x2="117.459" y2="51.402"/>
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="117.459,41.762 115.949,41.762 117.459,37.988 118.969,41.762 
        117.459,41.762  "/>
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="117.459,51.15 118.969,51.15 117.459,54.923 115.949,51.15 
        117.459,51.15   "/>

        <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" x1="116.053" y1="67.226" x2="116.053" y2="71.123"/>
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="116.053,67.478 114.543,67.478 116.053,63.705 117.563,67.478 
        116.053,67.478  "/>
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="116.053,70.871 117.563,70.871 116.053,74.646 114.543,70.871 
        116.053,70.871  "/>
    <text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 110.4395 52.4497)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="7">d</text>
    <text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 112.1309 48.9048)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="7">u</text>
    <text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 109.0215 75.4048)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="7">d</text>
    <text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 110.7168 71.8579)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="7">u</text>
    <text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 5.8345 57.0923)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="7">D</text>
    <path fill="#D9DADB" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M38.433,56.287
        c0-10.423,8.45-18.874,18.875-18.874c10.424,0,18.875,8.451,18.875,18.874c0,10.426-8.451,18.875-18.875,18.875
        C46.883,75.162,38.433,66.712,38.433,56.287L38.433,56.287z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M47.831,46.629
        c0-5.062,4.104-9.165,9.165-9.165c5.063,0,9.165,4.104,9.165,9.165s-4.102,9.165-9.165,9.165
        C51.934,55.794,47.831,51.691,47.831,46.629L47.831,46.629z"/>
    <path fill="#B1B3B4" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M49.946,46.629
        c0-3.894,3.156-7.05,7.05-7.05c3.895,0,7.049,3.157,7.049,7.05s-3.155,7.05-7.049,7.05C53.102,53.679,49.946,50.523,49.946,46.629
        L49.946,46.629z"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M119.648,63.031H59.502 M119.648,74.72
        H61.301 M121.057,37.314H62.559 M121.057,54.998h-56.85 M66.221,44.898V5.377 M63.672,43.399V5.377 M59.327,10.172h-2.848"/>
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="59.075,10.172 59.075,8.663 62.85,10.172 59.075,11.682 59.075,10.172    
        "/>

        <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" x1="70.715" y1="10.172" x2="79.408" y2="10.172"/>
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="70.967,10.172 70.967,11.682 67.193,10.172 70.967,8.663 70.967,10.172   
        "/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 72.9902 5.8345)" font-family="'FoundryFormSans-Book'" font-size="7">s</text>
    <path fill="#87888A" d="M38.611,56.263h37.385c0,0-0.068,2.58-0.697,5.1c-0.648,2.586-2.127,5.16-3.703,7.006
        c-2.023,2.375-4.693,4.168-5.793,4.619c-1.1,0.453-3.105,1.361-4.076,1.619c0,0-2.77,0.49-3.934,0.49s-3.844-0.148-5.202-0.537
        c-1.358-0.389-4.266-1.615-5.452-2.477c-1.423-1.035-3.539-2.889-4.314-3.924s-2.305-3.016-2.887-4.633s-1.226-4.268-1.291-4.721
        C38.583,58.353,38.611,56.263,38.611,56.263L38.611,56.263z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M51.224,68.933
        c0-3.238,2.626-5.865,5.866-5.865s5.865,2.627,5.865,5.865c0,3.24-2.625,5.865-5.865,5.865S51.224,72.173,51.224,68.933
        L51.224,68.933z"/>
    <path fill="#B1B3B4" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3398" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" d="M52.758,68.933
        c0-2.393,1.939-4.332,4.332-4.332s4.332,1.939,4.332,4.332s-1.94,4.332-4.332,4.332S52.758,71.326,52.758,68.933L52.758,68.933z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Now, I don't know much about SVG at all, but I think there may be something wrong with them. Because if I look at the HTML page using FireBug or the web inspector in Safari, and hold the cursor over the svg elements in the code, the shadowed rectangle that indicates the area of the element doesn't coincide with the actual image. Rather, it is shown as a shadow rectangle outside of the image, and sometimes taking up almost the entire page...

So could the problem somehow be related to the SVG code? What's strange though, is that none of this is causing any problems in the other browsers, not even Chrome, which I would expect to behave very similarly to Safari...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing attributes `classid` => `type` and `src` => `data`, I can't even view my SVG script otherwise. This CSS did the trick for me:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Oh, one more thing, my browsers cache the SVG when displayed with `object`, so you might also want to clear the browser cache. For some reason `embed` isn't cached.

Full example:

**rect.svg**

```
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  viewBox="0 0 400 200">
    <rect x="110" y="50" width="200" height="150" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

**demo.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="image/svg+xml" src="rect.svg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had actually posted the wrong object element code. Please see my edit. So I was using the same attributes you suggested already. Also, I tried setting the height on the body and html, but it didn't change anything. Actually though, you are very right about the browser cache. It is especially difficult to get rid of the cache on Safari for some reason, so it's hard to know sometimes if I'm seeing updates. I do empty it, but it doesn't always take (seen by adding test code like javascript alerts). I've tried this enough to know it's not working though...

Comment: Added an example that works in safari, is it useable? Observe I used `embed` instead, it isn't cached (and more terse) than `object`.

Comment: Well, I tried your example, and it shows up fine, but I am not able to scale that one either by setting width and height values on the embed or object (tried both). Are you? I would have expected the rectangle to fill the entire screen, given that you have set 100% in the css on it, but it didn't...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had problem with caching as well. If you remove all `px` from the svg file it works.

Comment: Right, well yes, it does grow a bit now. Still, maybe I'm not understanding SVG well enough, but what I get from the 100/100% values on the embed is an embed element that does indeed fill the entire page, but with an svg element that only fills part of it (and oddly aligned to the right of the screen) and a rectangle that fills upp even less (about 600px width, out of an available 1664px screen). What I want from my images is that if I set 100%, I should get it to fill the entire space with the image itself. And if I remove the height attribute it doesn't work, which it did in other browsers.

Comment: You want to stretch the content or fill the whole screen so some content ends up outside the screen? This is done with `preserveAspectRatio`, the former can be achieved with `none` and the latter with `xMidYMid slice`. More examples if you scroll down a little here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute

Comment: I want it to extend proportionally, and that is default, right? So I shouldn't need the ‘preserveAspectRatio’ attribute if I'm correct? I have never seen the image distorted when scaling, that's not the problem. The problem is that it doesn't fill up the entire available area, as it does in the other browsers.

Comment: Default is `xMidYMid meet`, which fits all content. For filling the screen and preserve proportions use `slice` instead of `meet`.